# Failing to convert raw binary/hex to int interpretation

Tags: qt

I'm trying to convert raw hex/binary data to different file types.

```
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QByteArray package;
package.append( QByteArray::fromHex("a1")); 
// "a1" is what is written to the memory, not the string representation of "a1"

qDebug() << package.toHex();  // "a1"
qDebug() << package;          // "�" 
qDebug() << package.toInt();  // 0 
}
```

Why is the int representation `0` and not `161`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toInt` has totally different purpose. It parses string representation of integer. If you want integer representing the value of the first byte of the array, use `package[0]`. It has `char` type. I don't remember how `qDebug()` represents `char` type, but if you have any problems with it, just static_cast it to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2):

`QByteArray::toInt` expects that `QByteArray` contains a string of characters (in ASCII probably), not the binary representation of the number.

If you want to convert binary representation to integer you can use reinterpret_cast:

```
int i = *reinterpret_cast<quint8*>(package.constData());
```

Or better use qFromBigEndian/qFromLittleEndian:

```
int i = qFromLittleEndian<quint8>((const uchar*)package.constData())
```

In both cases you must know exactly in what format the number is stored and use proper type and endianness.